# Configure list of servers for devpi

Tags: python, pip, pypi, devpi

I am running a [devpi-server](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/quickstart-pypimirror.html) locally in my laptop, so that I can work offline whenever I have no internet connection (this only works if devpi has had the chance to locally cache the packages that I need, of course)

Currently I have the `devpi-server` configured with default settings, so that it is looking for packages in the standard `PyPi`.

I would like to configure the `devpi-server` to use a list of servers to find packages:

- a private PyPi server, where we are publishing our internal libraries: `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyyy/simple/`
- the standard PyPi servers, for the usual Python ecosystem: `https://www.python.org/pypi`

Question: is it possible to configure `devpi` with a list of servers to try?

I do not find this option in the [devpi documentation](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/index.html).

Packages should be search in the list of servers: if a package is not found in the first server, it should look for it in the second, until the end of the list is reached and a "not found" message is replied.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by combining Devpi's index mirroring and the index inheritance feature.

Assuming you have a user `bob` on your Devpi server,

1. create an index mirroring your private server: `devpi index -c private type=mirror mirror_url=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyyy/simple/`.
2. Create an index inheriting from `/root/pypi` and the newly created mirror: `devpi index -c all bases=/bob/all,/root/pypi`

Afterwards you should be able to get all packages from `/bob/all`.